# SWT use transform and draw with floating point positions

Tags: swt, 2d, eclipse-rcp

I want to implement charting in SWT and I want to use GC.transform to transform the coordinates into a normalized form (origin in canvas center and the borders are -1 and 1 in X and Y direction). Later on I multiply a factor to get the canvas itself the area of the graph to draw the values on it without additional transformation.

My problem is now, I do not find methods to draw to the cancas in SWT with floating point coordinates...

Is there a faciltiy in SWT to draw with floating point coordinates and Transform? I think about something like Graphics2D in Swing. Is there anything like that in SWT?

Comment: Short answer: no. You have to scale your coordinates to the pixel level yourself.

Comment: I was afraid so... I hoped, there was a third party library around which already implements this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any solution. I started coding my own transformation tools to get eveything painted correctly.